# Effective mass approximation Wannier function lattice vector operator approximate representation proof. Yu and Cardona

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, mass

I am having difficulty in Yu and Cardona 4th edition chapter 4 page 164, equation 4.9 to 4.10

I just do not understand how to go from line 4.9 to 4.10.

4.9:
$$
R_{op} \psi(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{n,\textbf{k}} A_n(\textbf{k}) \sum_{\mathbf{R_i}} (N^{-\frac{1}{2}}) (-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}}) exp^{i\textbf{k}. \mathbf{ R_{i} }} a_n (\mathbf{r-R_i}) 
$$

4.10:
$$
R_{op} \psi(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{n,\textbf{k}}(-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})  A_n(\textbf{k})\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) - \sum_{n,\textbf{k}}[(-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})  A_n(\textbf{k})]\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})
$$

Given that;
a)
$$
a_n(\mathbf{r-R_i}) = (N^{-\frac{1}{2}}) \sum_{\textbf{k}} exp^{-i\textbf{k}. \mathbf{ R_{i} }} \psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})
$$
And
b)
$$
\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = 
 (N^{-\frac{1}{2}}) \sum_{\mathbf{R_i}} exp^{i\textbf{k}. \mathbf{ R_{i} }} a_n(\mathbf{r-R_i})
$$

subbing in a) into b) to get c);

$$
\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = 
 (N^{-1}) \sum_{\mathbf{R_i}} exp^{i\textbf{k}. \mathbf{ R_{i} }}\sum_{\textbf{k}} exp^{-i\textbf{k}. \mathbf{ R_{i} }} \psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})
$$

Keeping c in mind, my attempt is simply as follows;

sub in a) into 4.9 to get;
$$
R_{op} \psi(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{n,\textbf{k}} A_n(\textbf{k}) \sum_{\mathbf{R_i}} (N^{-\frac{1}{2}}) (-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}}) exp^{i\textbf{k}. \mathbf{ R_{i} }} (N^{-\frac{1}{2}}) \sum_{\textbf{k}} exp^{-i\textbf{k}. \mathbf{ R_{i} }} \psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})
$$

taking the N out to front, along with moving the derivitive out to front of the summation gives;
$$
R_{op} \psi(\mathbf{r}) =(N^{-1}) \sum_{n,\textbf{k}} A_n(\textbf{k}) (-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})\sum_{\mathbf{R_i}}   exp^{i\textbf{k}. \mathbf{ R_{i} }}  \sum_{\textbf{k}} exp^{-i\textbf{k}. \mathbf{ R_{i} }} \psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})
$$

then by c) the latter part of the above is psi, i.e;

EDIT: left in ($N^{-1}$) by mistake.
$$
R_{op} \psi(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{n,\textbf{k}} A_n(\textbf{k}) (-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})
$$
END EDIT.

Which is rather different to 4.10, presented again so you don't have to scroll :) ;
4.10:
$$
R_{op} \psi(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{n,\textbf{k}}(-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})  A_n(\textbf{k})\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) - \sum_{n,\textbf{k}}[(-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})  A_n(\textbf{k})]\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})
$$

I would very much appreciate it if anyone could direct me to my mistakes or even better, thoroughly explain them and how to obtain 4.10 the correct way.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that
$$
\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = 
 (N^{-\frac{1}{2}}) \sum_{\mathbf{R_i}} exp^{i\textbf{k}. \mathbf{ R_{i} }} a_n(\mathbf{r-R_i})
$$
rewrite (4.9) successively:
$$
R_{op} \psi(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{n,\textbf{k}} A_n(\textbf{k}) \sum_{\mathbf{R_i}} (N^{-\frac{1}{2}}) (-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}}) exp^{i\textbf{k}. \mathbf{ R_{i} }} a_n (\mathbf{r-R_i}) = \\
=\sum_{n,\textbf{k}} A_n(\textbf{k})  (-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})(N^{-\frac{1}{2}})\sum_{\mathbf{R_i}}  exp^{i\textbf{k}. \mathbf{ R_{i} }} a_n (\mathbf{r-R_i}) = \\
= \sum_{n,\textbf{k}} A_n(\textbf{k}) (-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = \\
= \sum_{n,\textbf{k}}(-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})  \left[A_n(\textbf{k})\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})\right] - \sum_{n,\textbf{k}}[(-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})  A_n(\textbf{k})]\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})
$$
So perhaps there's something wrong with the normalization of the (a) formula?

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I made a mistake in my latex, and left in a ($N^{-1}$) by mistake in my penultimate line.
So your suggestion about the normalization would be right if what I had typed was correct. Sorry.

I realised that I was just being a bit dumb, and not seeing that;
$$
\sum_{n,\textbf{k}}(-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})  \left[A_n(\textbf{k})\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})\right] = \sum_{n,\textbf{k}}[(-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})  A_n(\textbf{k})]\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})
+ 
\sum_{n,\textbf{k}} A_n(\textbf{k}) (-i \frac{d}{d\textbf{k}})\psi_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) 
$$
Thanks again!

Comment: Happens. Good luck!